# How to make collapsing toolbar square for all devices?

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I got the collapsing toolbar.  The image inside it has to be square but on devices, with big the screen, it is not. How can I set it up to let image be all the time square and make image full width and hight?

At the same time toolbar has to be collapsed it cant be fixed and frozen.

The code of activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/friend_activity_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:contentDescription="Default Avatar"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/avatar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/meta_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/friend_activity_tv_name"
                    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                    android:text="NAME"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/friend_activity_tv_age"
                        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="AGE"
                        android:textColor="#8fff"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/friend_activity_tv_country"
                        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                        android:text="COUNTRY"
                        android:textColor="#8fff"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <!--android:src="@drawable/default_avatar"-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">



            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/friend_activity_cardview_about"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_list_friendDescription"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/friend_activity_cardview_buttons_block"
                android:layout_below="@+id/friend_activity_cardview_about"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/my_profile_linear_likers_visitors"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/friend_activity_btn_add_friend"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                        android:paddingRight="25dp"
                        android:text="+ ADD FRIEND"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/friend_activity_btn_start_chat"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                        android:paddingRight="25dp"
                        android:text="WRITE MESSAGE"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/friend_activity_cardview_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/friend_activity_cardview_buttons_block"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/settings_image_btn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                        android:paddingRight="25dp"
                        android:text="@string/check_your_search_parameters"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/my_profile_tv_also_like"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/settings_image_btn"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/you_may_also_like_them"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/my_profile_recyler"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/my_profile_tv_also_like" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/friend_activity_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to programmatically set the height within onCreate

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;

        AppBarLayout abl=findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams ap=(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) abl.getLayoutParams();
        ap.height=width;

        abl.setLayoutParams(ap);
```

in the resource xml, on AppBarLayout
you also have to set

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

otherwise the square will start from the very top (including status bar battery, notification etc.), unless you want the square to begin from there.